# Handling multiple calls when device is connected via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, hfp

A device is connected to the Head Unit of the car via Bluetooth. There is an active call which is already going on. Then I get another call.

My question is, how should I display or notify user about the second incoming call without disturbing the first call?

Comment: The both sides have passed Bluetooth certification and should support such cases natively (if they declared support of such features). What are you develop, head unit, device or some application for one of them?

Comment: I should make android source code changes to meet this requirement which will be then put it into the head unit of the car.

Comment: Such features as `Three-way calling`, `Respond and Hold`, `Enhanced Call Control` and `Enhanced Call Status` are optional to implement for Bluetooth Handsfree unit (HFP client in Android). If your head unit should support them all, HFP client will keep a list of currently active, held and ringing calls and broadcast any changes in this list. In the "worst" case UI should dynamically show this list of calls and allow a user to answer/terminate or put on hold any of them. If your requirements limit use cases only by indication of the second call, you will need only a notification message in UI.

Comment: I connected my phone to head unit and I got a call from a number. I started a conversation. Later I got a call from another number while I was in a call but the Head Unit did not show me any notification or UI for this call. My mobile was showing the second call coming. So what should I make changes in android source code changes so as to get the UI for the second call as well.

Comment: I see the following possibilities: 1. information about the second call is not sent by a smartphone. AG and HF send one to another lists of supported features.

Comment: I see the following possibilities: 1. information about the second call is not sent by a smartphone. AG and HF send one to another lists of supported features and should use only features from these lists. You need to look into BT HCI snooplog to be sure that information about the second call is sent. 2. Head unit UI irnores information about the second call. `BluetoothHeadsetClient` should broadcast `ACTION_CALL_CHANGED` intents with `BluetoothHeadsetClientCall` about the both calls. In this case you need to look into head unit code processing these intents.

Comment: BTW what is version of Android in the head unit?

Comment: Android Pie (9)